# Obstacles management in Moveit

Tags: moveit, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would be delighted if someone can explain very clearly.

I have recently started working on a robot that has a Jaco Arm. (MetraLab Scitos G5).

I am using the ASUS xtion pro for the obstacle avoidance. Once this is done, I am able to view the Octree in the monitored_planning_scene topic (using rviz).

**1.** I also found that I could specify collision objects using the PlanningSceneInterface Class. What is the difference between the two approaches?

**2.** Also, what is the exact approach to using a PlanningSceneMonitor. In the planning scene tutorial, it is mentioned that the PlanninSceneMonitor is the elegant way to manage a Planning Scene. But, is there a tutorial for the PlanningSceneMonitor?

**3.** I saw that the PlanningSceneMonitor has a protected function called "excludeWorldObjectFromOctree()" .

Sometimes when I try to grasp an object (using xtion for obstacle avoidance), the plan fails since there is a potential collision between the fingers of the JACO arm and the object that I intend to pickup. I thought I could add it as a World object using the Planning Scene Interface (this I am able to do) and then use the "excludeWorldObjectFromOctree()" method to exclude the object from being considered for collision checking. Is there a more straight forward way of excluding a world object from collision checking?

**4.** I have somewhat understood how you could modify the AllowedCollisionMatrix. But then, how do I ensure that this ACM is updated to the current Planning Scene? I expect that there is a method in PlanningSceneInterface like "updateAllowedCollisionMatrix()" ? Am I guessing right? or is there a serious error in my understanding?

Please clarify!

Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157716/obstacles-management-in-moveit/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2014-04-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The octomap is updated live from your Xtion sensor data. The collision
objects are added by you. They are used to add collision objects that
you know the position of; the most common way is to have some sort of
object recognition node that recognizes, for example, tabletop objects,
and adds these objects as collision objects to the PlanningSceneWorld.
(If you look at moveit_msgs/PlanningSceneWorld, you can see that it has
one octomap and a list of collision objects).

You can add objects by either publishing to the "/collision_object"
topic, or by using a convenience function from the move_group C++
interface.

Once a collision object is added to the PlanningScene, the voxels that
overlap with it are automatically filtered out of the octomap. You do
not need to call excludeWorldObjectFromOctree() yourself (that's
probably why it's protected).

By default, collision checking is done between all robot links and the
octomap, and between all robot links and each collision object.
However, you can disable collision checks between certain robot links
and certain collision objects, and that's exactly what you should do:
disable collision checking between the fingers and the object you're
trying to pick up. There are basically two ways to do it:

1. Disable the collision checks before calling the move_group action.
   All calls to the move_group action after that will ignore those
   collisions. You'll have to remember to re-enable the collisions
   afterwards.
2. Specify the allowed collisions for that specific move_group call
   only, as a parameter of that action call. This is somewhat nicer in
   my opinion.

For (1), there are a couple of options:

1a. Using the PlanningSceneMonitor. From C++, I think this is better
than the solution (1b) below. It should go something like this
(warning, completely untested!):

```
#include <moveit/planning_scene_monitor/planning_scene_monitor.h>

planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitorPtr psm = planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitorPtr(
    new planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitor("robot_description", tf, "name"));

planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRW planning_scene = planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRW(psm);

collision_detection::AllowedCollisionMatrix acm = planning_scene->getAllowedCollisionMatrix();

// TODO: modify acm here as explained in the PlanningScene tutorial: http://docs.ros.org/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/planning_scene_tutorial.html

As an inspiration, I found digging through this code helpful: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/tree/hydro-devel/visualization/planning_scene_rviz_plugin
```

1b. Publishing to the "/planning_scene" topic. From Python, it looks
like this:

```
    self._pubPlanningScene = rospy.Publisher('planning_scene', PlanningScene)
    rospy.wait_for_service('/get_planning_scene', 10.0)
    get_planning_scene = rospy.ServiceProxy('/get_planning_scene', GetPlanningScene)
    request = PlanningSceneComponents(components=PlanningSceneComponents.ALLOWED_COLLISION_MATRIX)
    response = get_planning_scene(request)

    acm = response.scene.allowed_collision_matrix
    if not 'button' in acm.default_entry_names:
        # add button to allowed collision matrix
        acm.default_entry_names += ['button']
        acm.default_entry_values += [True]

        planning_scene_diff = PlanningScene(
                is_diff=True,
                allowed_collision_matrix=acm)

        self._pubPlanningScene.publish(planning_scene_diff)
        rospy.sleep(1.0)
```

For (2), you can use the same planning_scene_diff that I computed above
by putting it into your MoveGroupGoal.planning_options.planning_scene_diff.
It's important that you really get the current allowed collision matrix first
and then modify it, as shown above.

Note that I added the collision object to the default_entry_names,
which means that collisions between that object and *all* robot links are
allowed, not just the fingers. That's bad, but I couldn't make it work
otherwise.

Another option for you is to use the `pick` action instead of implementing
it yourself with move_group calls. It wraps the move_group action, and it
automatically handles the allowed collision matrix etc. for you. One small
example of using it is here:

https://github.com/uos/calvin_robot/blob/hydro/calvin_pick_n_place/src/calvin_pick_n_place.cpp

> *2.* Also, what is the exact approach to using a
> PlanningSceneMonitor. In the planning scene tutorial, it is mentioned
> that the PlanninSceneMonitor is the elegant way to manage a Planning
> Scene. But, is there a tutorial for the PlanningSceneMonitor?

Not that I know of. The Planning Scene tutorial says that it's
"discussed in detail in the next tutorial", but that never got written
if I'm correct. (Please, everyone, correct me if I'm wrong!)

> *3.* I saw that the PlanningSceneMonitor has a protected function
> called "excludeWorldObjectFromOctree()" .
>
> Sometimes when I try to grasp an object (using xtion for obstacle
> avoidance), the plan fails since there is a potential collision
> between the fingers of the JACO arm and the object that I intend to
> pickup. I thought I could add it as a World object using the Planning
> Scene Interface (this I am able to do) and then use the
> "excludeWorldObjectFromOctree()" method to exclude the object from
> being considered for collision checking. Is there a more straight
> forward way of excluding a world object from collision checking?

See above. Once you add a CollisionObject, it is automatically excluded
from the octomap, but of course not from collision checking.

> *4.* I have somewhat understood how you could modify the
> AllowedCollisionMatrix. But then, how do I ensure that this ACM is
> updated to the current Planning Scene? I expect that there is a
> method in PlanningSceneInterface like
> "updateAllowedCollisionMatrix()" ? Am I guessing right? or is there a
> serious error in my understanding?

See above.

> Please clarify!
>
> Thank you so much!
>
> Chittaranjan S Srinivas
>
> Orebro University

Cheers,
Martin

I have posted this from the reply on moveit-users google mailing list.

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on 2015-05-19**:
Quoted from this answer: "It's important that you really get the current allowed collision matrix first and then modify it, as shown above." Why is this the case? What is the meaning of the `is_diff` argument, if not to indicate that the acm published is the diff between current and desired acm?